# Angular HTTP within a HTTP Interceptor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise, angular-http-interceptors

I need to append the necessary HMAC headers to a request.  This should not be very difficult however I am starting to get frustrated.  What is wrong with the following code.  The actual http call I am doing works; I have run this call myself and it returns the necessary data. It does not work inside the interceptor.

I merely want to get the current implementation working before I add whitelist or blacklist and other customizable data for this interceptor.  This is not a question about hmac however but with promises.

The error in this interceptor is with the entire promise line starting at $http(...).  When i remove this block and use it as is (minus promise execution) it works fine.  As soon as i uncomment the line it gets stuck in a loop and crashes chrome.  Everywhere I have read says this is how it is done, but this clearly does not work.

```
function requestInterceptor(config){
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.get(hmacApiEndpoint, {cache: true}).then(function(data){
    console.log('HMAC - Success', data)
    deferred.resolve(config)
  }, function(config){
    console.log('HMAC - Error', config)
    deferred.resolve(config)
  })

  return deferred.promise;
}

return {
  request: requestInterceptor
};
```

Does this have something to do with the fact that angulars $http promise is a different implementation than that of '$q'?

Comment: will that `$http` call from request `requestInterceptor` will call `requestInterceptor` again? I doubt that it will call it recursively

Comment: @pankajparkar, I'm almost certain it will... so, to avoid an infinite loop, you should only apply the interceptor to urls other than `hmacApiEndpoint`. And `$http` returns the same promise + and additional `.success`/`.error` -  so, it is the same or compatible

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It doesn't look like you are actually amending the `config` with the newly obtainted HMAC.

Also, you'd need to protect against your `requestInterceptor` intercepting the call to obtain the HMAC, thus resulting in an infinite loop.

And lastly, you don't need `deferred` here - just return the promise produced by `$http` (or `$http.then()`):

```
function requestInterceptor(config){
  var $http = $injector.get('$http');

  // just return, if this is a call to get HMAC
  if (config.url === hmacApiEndpoint) return config;

  return $http.get(hmacApiEndpoint, {cache: true})
    .then(function(response){
      console.log('HMAC - Success', response.data)

      // not sure where the HMAC needs to go
      config.headers.Authorization = response.data;
      return config;
    })
    .catch(function(){
       return $q.reject("failed to obtain HMAC");
    });
}

return {
  request: requestInterceptor
};
```

Comment: good solution, but could you explain me how will not call the interceptor for `$http.get` you are making for `HMAC`

Comment: @pankajparkar, It will get called, but it will skip the inner `$http` call to (again) get the HMAC

Comment: @pankajparkar, how so? The `{cache: true}` setting would make it retrieve the previous result without an Ajax request. maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: then that make sense..cool solution..as you gave everytime..you are great..:) +1 from me

Comment: That is fantastic! And exactly what is happening.  I removed the hmac headers from this example because they are arbitrary.  The infinite loop is what I overlooked.

You are correct, the http interceptor is intercepting its own response and therefore never resolving.

The cache true will in a very naive sense only allow one call, however the original call is being intercepted so the cacheFactory is not being populated with the values, ever.

Thank you for this solution, everything you said makes perfect sense, I overlooked that recursive like loop.

Comment: Also let me explicate here that there should be a protocol check for https.  Hmac is only secure in a Public Key Infrastructure and therefore the transmission of the secrets in this  case (because hmac uses symmetric key encryption) needs to be done in a secure channel.

I can add a similar check at the beginning of this.